# PySpark map dataframe row values to distinct elements in a column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to map a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-------+-----------+
|    key|     value |
+-------+-----------+
|      A| ['x', 'y']|
|      B| ['y', 'z']|
|      C|      ['z']|
+-------+-----------+
```

To something like this

```
+-------+------------------------+
|    key|                  value |
+-------+------------------------+
|      A|{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}|
|      B|{'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 1}|
|      C|{'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 1}|
+-------+------------------------+
```

First dataframe in the column `value` contains the actual values for each key. The point is to map it against distinct elements in the whole column (value_name: 1 if exists in distinct elements else 0)

Comment: will there always be x, y and z in value columns and not more?

Comment: There can be more values in a column

Answer (score 2):

You can `explode` and `pivot`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col, create_map, count, explode, lit
from itertools import chain

df = sc.parallelize([
    ("A", ["x", "y"]), ("B", ["y", "z"]), ("C", ["z"])
]).toDF(["key", "value"])

cnts = df.withColumn("value", explode("value")).groupBy("key").pivot("value").count().na.fill(0)
value = create_map(*chain.from_iterable((lit(c), col(c)) for c in cnts.columns if c != "key"))

cnts.select("key", value.alias("value")).show(truncate=False)
# +---+---------------------------+
# |key|value                      |
# +---+---------------------------+
# |B  |Map(x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 1)|
# |C  |Map(x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 1)|
# |A  |Map(x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 0)|
# +---+---------------------------+
```

or `explode`, collect distinct values and apply `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

keys = [k for k in chain.from_iterable(df.select(explode("value")).distinct().collect())]

def f(keys):
    @udf("map<string,long>")
    def _(values):
        d = dict.fromkeys(keys, 0)
        for v in values:
            d[v] += 1
        return d
    return _

df.select("key", f(keys)("value").alias("value")).show(truncate=False)
# 
# +---+---------------------------+
# |key|value                      |
# +---+---------------------------+
# |A  |Map(x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 0)|
# |B  |Map(x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 1)|
# |C  |Map(x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 1)|
# +---+---------------------------+
```